# Is there a budget accommodation in Vientiane, Laos with kitchen?

Tags: budget, food-and-drink, accommodation, laos, vientiane

I'm travelling with two chef friends and we'll be in Laos for Christmas and New Year.

They'd like to stay in a cheap place (low end of Vientiane price range) which has a kitchen they can use.

It doesn't matter if the kitchen is in the room, is a shared kitchen in a hostel, or if the place such as a guesthouse that has a kitchen normally used by staff that is known to let guests use it on request.

So far in our first two days the hostels, guesthouses, and cheap hotels we've checked don't have such kitchen facilities.

We're wondering if any of the travel experts know of a place or can help find a place where we can cook up a feast during our stay.

Answer (score 1):

According to booking.com, there are twelve facilities in Vientiane with kitchen facilities, at least two of them seem to be rather affordable, [take a look at the options here](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-us.html?sid=aac21ff3984936ed2a0a94cad7bb8959;dcid=4;checkin_monthday=9;checkin_year_month=2015-1;checkout_monthday=10;checkout_year_month=2015-1;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;dest_id=-2669740;dest_type=city;no_rooms=1;or_radius=0;order=price_for_two;pr=0%2C220;pr_cur_code=MYR;review_score_group=empty;score_min=0;si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi;ss=Vientiane%2C%20Laos;ss_raw=vientiane;ssb=empty&;;nflt=mealplan%3D8000999%3Buf%3D4292297556%3B;unchecked_filter=uf) and make your choice.